# How to use type assertion on @input() variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a union type of several interfaces that share a common parent through inheritance.  That union type is passed on to specific components. Those components will only ever be one of the child types.  How can I assert the type on the child component?

Example:

```
interface Common {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

interface Child1 extends Common {
  c: string;
}

interface Child2 extends Common {
  d: string;
}

type Union = Child1 | Child2;
```

The parent component has a variable

```
data: Union;
```

and passes it to child components like so:

```
<app-child1 [data]="data"></app-child1>
<app-child2 [data]="data"></app-child2>
```

The child component will only ever be one of those types so I should be able to assert it somehow:

```
@Input() data: Child1;
```

Currently this will throw a type error claiming Child1 is missing properties.

I've tried these `@Input() data: Union as Child1;` and `<app-child1 [data]="data as Child1">` but those just break.

How can I assert this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just cast to any:

```
<app-child1 [data]="$any(data)"></app-child1>
<app-child2 [data]="$any(data)"></app-child2>
```

---

Or cast to the expected type like this:

In your parent component:

```
asChildOne = (data: Union): Child1 => data as Child1;
asChildTwo = (data: Union): Child2 => data as Child2;
```

In the parent template:

```
<app-child1 [data]="asChildOne(data)"></app-child1>
<app-child2 [data]="asChildTwo(data)"></app-child2>
```

---

Or if you want to render the child only if the type is really the type it needs, you can do some [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

Somewhere near your interfaces:

```
export function isCommon(obj: any): obj is Common {
  return obj && 'a' in obj && 'b' in obj;
}

export function isChild1(obj: any): obj is Child1 {
  return isCommon(obj) && 'c' in obj;
}

export function isChild2(obj: any): obj is Child2 {
  return isCommon(obj) && 'd' in obj;
}
```

In your parent component:

```
isChildOne = (data: Union): data is Child1 => isChild1(data)
isChildTwo = (data: Union): data is Child2 => isChild2(data)
asChildOne = (data: Union): Child1 => data as Child1;
asChildTwo = (data: Union): Child2 => data as Child2;
```

In the parent template:

```
<app-child1 *ngIf="isChildOne(data)" [data]="asChildOne(data)"></app-child1>
<app-child2 *ngIf="isChildTwo(data)" [data]="asChildTwo(data)"></app-child2>
```

Comment: Lots of good suggestions here, it just would be really verbose to make component properties for each possible type. I have ~15 or so possibilities which would really clutter up the parent component.  Using the setter in child component suggested by Yousaf is much cleaner imo.

Comment: Well, casting to `any` with `$any()` (the first suggestion), doesn't require any properties in a component and is cleaner that doing a setter `@Input()` and casting to `unknown`.

Comment: Dang, that is a good point.  I focused too much on the latter part of your answer.  I have ingrained it into my head that I should avoid using ```any``` if possible, but I can't think of any downside to using it in this scenario

Comment: If you're not gonna use any properties of `Child1` or `Child2` in the parent component and just pass it as an `@Input()` then there's no difference between casting to `any` or to the appropriate type (`Child1`/`Child2`). Field in the child component is properly typed.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to point out any problems

```
// You can use this setter pattern, I use this
class ChildComponent {
    data: Child1;
    @Input() set( d: Union ) {
        data = d as unknown as Child1;
        // One problem is that you can slip the 'd' prop in the UNION type object from the parent but you can always use if statement to remedy that
    }
}
```

and in Parent

```
<app-child1 [data]="data">
```

Comment: Any reason to cast as unknown first? I was able to cast directly as Child1 using this pattern

Comment: Also, might be a syntax issue here... I had to write this: ```@Input() set data(d: Union){``` otherwise parent component complained the data property didn't exist on the child component

Comment: Yeah you are right unknown was not necessary, I wrote as I was thinking so maybe I missed naming the setter method

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this only in child component

```
@Input() data: Union;
```

Do not pass type while passing or calling child component

```
<app-child1 [data]="data as Child1"> // not this
<app-child1 [data]="data"> // pass only data
```

Comment: I want to specify the Child1 in the child component though.  I would get further typescript errors when trying to access child specific properties in that component.

Comment: you can do that using like this if((this.data as Child1).c) {}. I have done it in this way sometimes

Comment: I would have to do that for every single property call in that component. In my actual project there are a lot of properties.  Maybe there is a way to assert it globally?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like this,

```
@Input() data: Child1 | Child2;
```